# write a program to insert an element in an array at a specific position don't use any function in python

Tags: python

i want to add any specific number in any specific position. so when i come up with solution i get index out of range or list out of range(where the list and array in python are growing dynamically).

```
from array import *
a = int(input("how many number you want to inout in an arery"))
ary = array('i',[])
for i in range(a):
    d = int(input("enter number")) # suppose i take [2,5,4,3,8]
    ary.append(d)
pos = int(input("Enter position number")) #i take position is 4
val = int(input("enter value number"))    # and value is 10
c = a-1
while(c >= pos-1):
    ary[c+1] = ary[c]
    c-=1
ary[pos-1]= val
print(ary)

[2,5,4,10,3,8]
```

Comment: What is`array('i',[])`? As far as I know, python does not have a built-in `array` function.

Comment: from array import *

Comment: what are you inputting to replicate the error? which line is throwing the error?

Comment: I see. Why you cannot use [array.insert(i, x)](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/array.html#array.array.insert)? It does exactly what you want.

Comment: Seems like this question is referring to [this array ](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) and not list!

Comment: `ary[pos-1].append(ary[val])` makes no sense: `ary[pos-1]` is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

What about slicing? Inspired from how you 'd do this with a `list`. The following adds the value 100 in position 2 (indexing from 0 and not 1)

```
>>> a = array('i',[1,2,3,4,5])
>>> value = 100
>>> pos = 2  # 0-based
>>> a = array('i', a[:pos]) + array('i', [value]) + array('i', a[pos:])
>>> a
array('i', [1, 2, 100, 3, 4, 5])
```

Note that I am not familiar with `array`s but from what I read they seem to behave like `list`s. As such, the above way to insert might not be the most efficient since it is creating 3 new arrays and concatenates them into `a`

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get this error message is that your array's size increases with 1, because you add a new value, but you forget to actually add that position to your array. So, to solve your problem, you need to add a position, then do the corresponding movements.

The algorithm is this:

1. you append a position to the array;
2. you add the last number of the previous array to the new one;
3. you cycle through the array, from the end to the position, and move the numbers one position towards the end;
4. when you reach the position, you insert the number read from the keyboard.

In Python, the code is:

```
from array import *

a = int(input("how many numbers you want to input in an array? "))
ary = array('i', [])
for i in range(a):
    d = int(input("enter number"))  # suppose i take [2,5,4,3,8]
    ary.append(d)
pos = int(input("Enter position number"))  # i take position is 4
val = int(input("enter value number"))  # and value is 10
ary.append(ary[len(ary) - 1]) 
x = len(ary) - 1
while x >= pos:
    ary[x] = ary[x - 1]
    x -= 1
ary[pos - 1] = val
print(ary)
```

Another thing: `ary` is the entire array. `ary[2]` is the 3rd element from the array. You can append to an array, but not to a position of it. Hence, an assignment like:

`ary[2].append(whatever)`

is wrong.

Comment: You're welcome! Please upvote and/or mark this answer as accepted so as other people will be helped in the future